# How to fix 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys )'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, export

I want to export an obect which is in this file,
config.js:

```
const CURRENT_YEAR = ( new Date() ).getFullYear()

export default { CURRENT_YEAR }
```

when I import it in footer.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import  CURRENT_YEAR  from '../../config'

const footer = () => (
    <div  >
       @NBA { CURRENT_YEAR } All rights reserved.
   </div>  
)

export default footer
```

there is no error in the cli but React throws this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {CURRENT_YEAR}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the brackets in your export as such:

```js
const CURRENT_YEAR = ( new Date() ).getFullYear()

export default CURRENT_YEAR
```

Otherwise you encapsulate the  Date into an object, alternatively you could do as such :

in config.js :

```
const CURRENT_YEAR = new Date().getFullYear();

const config = {
  CURRENT_YEAR
};

export default config;
```

in footer.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import config from "../../config";

function App() {
  return <div>
    @NBA {config.CURRENT_YEAR} All rights reserved.
    </div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you wrap your export in `{}` which turns `CURRENT_YEAR` into an object that looks like:

```
{ CURRENT_YEAR: 2019 }
```

Just export it like:

```
export default CURRENT_YEAR
```

Then `CURRENT_YEAR` can retain its value.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't exported the variable correctly, you need to export it like

```
const CURRENT_YEAR = ( new Date() ).getFullYear()

export default CURRENT_YEAR;
```

else `CURRENT_YEAR` in footer.js would be an object like `{CURRENT_YEAR: ( new Date() ).getFullYear()}`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `export default` with curly braces. Just `export default`:

```
export default CURRENT_YEAR;
```

If you wrap it in curly braces, it's evaluated like:

```
export default {{ date: 6/12/2019 };
```

Which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it can be resolved via destructing, so the footer.js can be this:

```
import React from 'react'
import style from './footer.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import  YEAR  from '../../config'

const { CURRENT_YEAR } = YEAR

const footer = () => (
    <div className={ style.right } >
        @NBA { CURRENT_YEAR } All rights reserved.
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I mean you could do that, but that seems like you're just complicating your code for no reason :(. Why go through the trouble of turning CURRENT_YEAR into an object when you export it, then destructuring it just so you get it back to its initial state.